# What does self comparable interface do in Collections Class?

Tags: java, generics, collections, interface, marker-interfaces

While practicing Reflection I came to know about `SelfComparable Interface` in `Collections` class

```
interface java.util.Collections$SelfComparable
```

**What does this interface use for ?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It doesn't do anything.  It is private so you can't import it.

It is really a comment that the type is "SelfComparable" and is not actually used.

Nothing implement this interface. The code which uses it relies on the fact it will be discarded at runtime.

```
public static <T> T max(Collection<? extends T> coll, Comparator<? super T> comp) {
    if (comp==null)
        return (T)max((Collection<SelfComparable>) (Collection) coll);
```

could have been

```
public static <T> T max(Collection<? extends T> coll, Comparator<? super T> comp) {
    if (comp==null)
        return (T)max(/*SelfComparable*/ (Collection) coll);
```

as it will be ignored at runtime.

Comment: does do -> doesn't do ?

Comment: @Kent what does that mean :)

Comment: @Prateek it means I mixed up my words. :)

Comment: @Peter means commenting it would not have any impact.

Answer (score 2):

From [source](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/util/Collections.java.html):

> ```
> private interface SelfComparable extends Comparable<SelfComparable> {}
> ```

This is nothing more than a marker over `Comparable<SelfComparable>`, which basically means that it is a marker for comparables that compare to self. Its use is somewhat superfluous.

It's used as:

> ```
> return (T)min((Collection<SelfComparable>) (Collection) coll);
> ```

on [line 662](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/util/Collections.java.html#661) where it basically casts a collection to `Collection`, and then performs a cast for the generic parameter to be a `SelfComparable` which just extends `Comparable`.